# Build failed with an exception Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. >

Tags: build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib\main.dart on Snap 4G2 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   Output:  error: resource **android:attr/fontVariationSettings** not found.
  >   C:\Users\rajesh.yadav\AndroidStudioProjects\microfinance\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:337: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\rajesh.yadav.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\333594338724db9cac843ec5e02726f3\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\

C:\Users\rajesh.yadav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\rajesh.yadav\AndroidStudioProjects\microfinance\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\rajesh.yadav\AndroidStudioProjects\microfinance\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          C:\Users\rajesh.yadav\AndroidStudioProjects\microfinance\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\

BUILD FAILED in 2m 25s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

You're using compile SDK version 27 (that's why `android-27\android.jar` is passed to AAPT2), but you or one of your dependencies is using resources from SDK version 28 (i.e. `fontVariationSettings` and `ttcIndex`). Update your compile SDK version in your `build.gradle` file to version 28.